# Rails 3 - Recursive Relationship - Comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, recursive-datastructures

I'm trying to create a recursive relationship in rails so that comments can have replies (using the same model comment.rb). So basically, a comment has many comments(as replies) and a comment can belong to only one comment.

I have the fk in my migration, but was wondering what needs to be on my comment.rb model.

Is this the proper way?

```
has_many :comments, :as => :reply
belongs_to :comment
```

Sorry, just want to make sure I'm doing this the correct way.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you plan to do a threading type of thing, you might want to look into https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set to save you the trouble :)